# Where can I buy a Stealth Boy?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I just can't seem to find a Stealth Boy and I need to do some sneaking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No NPC sells Stealth Boys, and they are rarer than in Fallout 3. You may find some in locations with Nightkin (in their corpses or around the area). [Here's](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Stealth_Boy_%28Fallout:_New_Vegas%29#Locations) a list with some locations where you can find Stealth Boys.

Comment: @Biff MaGriff I did the 'Come Fly With Me' mission near Novac, that involved many Nightskin, and I got a lot of Stealth Boys. Go check this mission.

Comment: Dang I guess I shouldn't have sold so many to the gun runners :(

Comment: @BiffMaGriff I learned that lesson the hard way as well. Sold a couple of them, I didn't use them much, then came to steal from the Gun Runner's and needed one... didn't have one. I had to go running around the mojave looking for one. Eventually succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

There is a stealth boy in the school house in Goodspring safe also